# Why is Internet Explorer is not calling my VBscript event handlers?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I am trying to automate some form filling in Internet Explorer through VBscript but I have run into a problem.

My first problem was dealing with Internet Explorer's Integrity Mode.  I solved that by following the steps here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/03/internet-explorer-automation-protected-mode-lcie-default-integrity-level-medium.aspx.

My second problem was that using Busy and ReadyState combined to check if the page had loaded was not giving me the correct result, it was completing before the final page actually loaded.  I believe this is to with the redirect I get; I am in a corporate environment so before I get to my form, single sign on checks who I am first.

My thought was to use the event callback DocumentComplete instead to check if the final page has loaded, but I cannot see my function getting called.

I have included a code snippet below:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objIeMedium
Set objIeMedium = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")

Dim isDocumentComplete : isDocumentComplete = False

Sub objIeMedium_DocumentComplete(ByVal pdisp, ByVal url)
    Wscript.Echo "DocumentComplete"
    isDocumentComplete = True
End Sub

Sub objIeMedium_OnQuit()
    Wscript.Echo "Quitting"
    isDocumentComplete = True
End Sub

Sub objIeMedium_NavigateComplete(ByVal pdisp, ByVal url)
    Wscript.Echo "NavigateComplete"
    isDocumentComplete = True
End Sub

objIeMedium.Navigate("http://abc/xyz.aspx")
objIeMedium.Visible = True
'Do While objIeMedium.Busy And objIeMedium.ReadyState <> 4: WScript.Sleep 100: Loop

Do Until isDocumentComplete
    Wscript.Sleep 100
Loop

Wscript.Echo "Done"

objIeMedium.Quit
Set objIeMedium = Nothing
```

Am I doing anything obviously wrong?